# What is the difference between using Mat& and Mat in Opencv?

Tags: opencv, mat, iplimage

I have seen declarations like `Mat& img = imread("image")` and `Mat img = imread("image")`.
What is the difference between the two ?

Is there anything like `Mat*` ?

How can I use `IplImage` in a similar way to `Mat&` ?

Please Help!

Comment: possible duplicate of [What are the differences between pointer variable and reference variable in C++?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/57483/what-are-the-differences-between-pointer-variable-and-reference-variable-in-c)

Comment: @karlphillip I think it's worth a separate explanation, because the hidden pointer to image data in `cv::Mat` gives it some unexpected behavior for beginners